# Atualizar o SELECT box ao clicar em botão com base no MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho vários `select` no meu sistema, a ideia é que ele pesquise no banco de dados somente uma vez para atualizar os dados das `option` e somente atualizar novamente ao clicar em um botão.
Os usuários deste sistema não tem acesso à internet frequente para fazer consultas no banco de dados toda vez que clicar no `select`.
Encontrei algumas soluções como armazenar na `$_SESSION`, porem não sei se é o mais recomendado.

Comment: A resposta pode vir a ser prejudicial pois a maior objeção ao uso de armazenamento local sejam as vulnerabilidades de segurança associadas a ele. O armazenamento local compartilha muitas das mesmas características de um cookie, incluindo os mesmos riscos de segurança. Uma delas é a suscetibilidade a scripts entre sites, que roubam cookies para permitir que hackers se disfarcem de usuário com sua sessão de login para um site. Armazenar algo sensível em um arquivo de armazenamento local simplifica o processo de ataque, pois não precisa carregar o cookie .

Comment: Para seu tipo de problema existe a [API IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) que é uma API para armazenamento client-side de quantidades significantes de informações e buscas com alta performance por índices. Enquanto DOM Storage é útil para armazenamento de pequenas quantidade de dados, IndexedDB é a solução para grande porção de dados estruturados. Minha sugestão é que edite a pergunta e adicione um [mcve] para que a pergunta possa ser reaberta e  obtenha uma boa resposta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Neste caso, o recomendado é usar o objeto [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) do JavaScript, porém com alguns cuidados:

- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) é um objeto JSON de tipo próprio que permite o armazenamento de dados e informações no navegador local
- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) tem métodos acessores ([`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) e [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)) para acessar ou manipular seus atributos
- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) não permite que o usuário salve objetos dentro dele, apenas valores de texto **(string)** ou numérico **(int)**
- Quer salvar um JSON dentro do [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? Lembre-se de que ele não reconhece objetos e nem serializa por padrão, portanto ao adicionar um objeto JSON chame uma função do JavaScript para serializá-lo [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) e ser armazenado corretamente dentro do armazenamento local para evitar este tipo de problema futuramente:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O [`$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) da linguagem PHP faz algo semelhante ao [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) do JavaScript, a única diferença que no PHP o código é executado no lado do servidor, ou seja para pegar um valor de uma sessão no navegador é preciso de internet, já no JavaScript é possível pegá-lo sem necessariamente o cliente ter acesso a rede ou até mesmo em queda de internet, quando esteja trabalhando no sistema e a rede cai.

Mas sempre no início terá que haver uma conexão para atualizar os dados das `<option>` no [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) com as informações atualizadas no banco de dados.